# JavaScript for loop that alternates two constants

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I've been trying to use a for loop to make a code that alternates between two strings and ends with .toUpperCase , but I'm completely stuck. I'm "able" to do it with an array with two strings (and even so it has a mistake, as it ends with the first string of the array...), but not with two separate constants.
Could anyone offer some help?

```js
function repeteFrases(num) {
  const frases = ["frase um", "frase dois"];
  let result = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    result += i === num - 1 ? frases[0].toUpperCase() : `${frases[0]}, ${frases[1]}, `;
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(repeteFrases(2));
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the desired inputs and outputs.

Comment: Alternating between a 0 and a 1 could be done with a logical `and` to get the index.

Comment: Herectic Monkey, could you explain what you mean? Not sure I understand what I'm supposed to include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've almost got it.. I *think* what you're asking for is to repeat phrase one or two (alternating), and for the last version to be uppercase.  I notice someone else made your code executable, so I might be misunderstanding. We can test odd/even using the modulus operator (%), which keeps the access of `frases` to either the 0 or 1 position.  The other trick is to loop until one less phrase than needed, and append the last one as upper case.

```js
function repeteFrases(num) {
  const frases = ["frase um", "frase dois"];
  //Only loop to 1 less than the expected number of phrases
  const n=num-1;

  let result = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    //Note %2 means the result can only be 0 or 1
    //Note ', ' is a guess at inter-phrase padding
    result+=frases[i%2] + ', ';
  }
  //Append last as upper case
  return result+frases[n%2].toUpperCase();
}
console.log(repeteFrases(2));
console.log(repeteFrases(3));
```

Comment: I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

In order to alternate between two states you can use the parity of the index, i.e., the condition would be `i % 2 == 0`, like this:

```js
   function repeteFrases(num) {
     const frases = ["frase um", "frase dois"];
     let result = "";
     for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
       result += i % 2 == 0 ? frases[0].toUpperCase() : `${frases[0]}, ${frases[1]}, `;
     }
     return result;
   }
   console.log(repeteFrases(5));
```

Comment: I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `frases[i % frases.length]` to alternate the phrases (*however many there might be*)

```js
function repeteFrases(num) {
  const frases = ["frase um", "frase dois"];
  let result = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    const next = frases[i % frases.length];
    const isLast = (i === num - 1);
    result += isLast ? next.toUpperCase() : `${next}, `;
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(repeteFrases(5));
```

Comment: I appreciate the help.